# To get all rows where my boolean field is null in cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

I altered a table by adding a new column (let say x) of boolean type in **cassandra**. Now I want all the rows in which x is null.
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE x is null , something like that .. I have read in many vlogs that cassandra don't support null type.

So, please tell me if there is any other way to retrieve the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE col = something` is usually a very bad query for Cassandra until the `col` is at least partition key. As Cassandra is distributed system it will need to fetch data from all nodes and return it. When you have relatively big amount of data in Cassandra cluster, most probably this query will just timeout.

You can still perform similar query, but it will be more complicated. You can either:

- Use Spark with [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) (see documentation in the `doc` folder);
- Perform effective scanning of data on all nodes by splitting your query into multiple, covering individual token ranges, so you can process data on individual nodes in parallel, without overloading the coordinating node. I have [an example of Java code](https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/driver-1.x/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/TokenRangesScan.java) that you could use as a base, but Spark could be easier to implement.

P.S. I would recommend to start with the basics of Cassandra to understand how it works - it will make your life easier if you understand what you can do & what can't. For beginning you can start with [DS201 course on DataStax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/ds201-datastax-enterprise-6-foundations-of-apache-cassandra).

Comment: hi Alex, I would like to add the token sub query feature into my code but was wondering how much of a performance boost I am likely to see? At my current project we use a conservative replication factor, so each node has every replica. Does it still make sense to expect a boost by doing this?

Comment: It really depends on implementation. If you're doing this very often, then I would just suggest to deploy spark to cassandra nodes & enjoy special load balancing policy in the spark cassandra connector that will try to avoid network communication at all